# Counting letters in a text file - frequency

Tags: python

I have a given text file with letters a, b, .., z with their given occurence. I wrote it like this

```
"letter";"occurences"
a;105
b;29
...
z;0
```

I have to use this data to create a vector "freq" of length 26 containing the frequency of occurrence of each of the 26 letters from a to z.

```
def letterFrequency(small_text):
    filein = open("small_text.txt", "r") # Opens the file for reading
    lines = filein.readlines() # Reads all lines into an array
    smalltxt = "".join(lines) # Joins the lines into one big string
    freq = 0
    n = 1296
    for letter in lines:
        np.count_nonzero(letter)
        freq.append(letter)
        freq = letter/n
     return freq
print(letterFrequency('small_text.txt'))
```

The total number of n = 1296 which is relevant for the frequency which is given in % , expected output is therefore

```
[ 8.10185185 2.23765432 2.4691358 4.55246914
12.34567901
2.00617284 1.92901235 6.71296296 7.17592593
0.07716049
1.15740741 3.39506173 1.08024691 6.71296296
7.87037037
1.46604938 0.07716049 6.01851852 5.40123457
10.95679012
2.85493827 0.92592593 2.93209877 0.
1.54320988 0. ]
```

Since 105/1296 = 0.081

If anyone would want to help me and navigate me further thank you since my code isn't working!

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a list to store the values and append into this list

Also instead of hardcoding 1296 you should get the accumulated frequency and then divide by this.

```
def letterFrequency(filename):
    frequencies = []
    letters = []
    accum = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            letter, freq = line.split(';')
            try: 
                freq = int(freq)
            except ValueError:       # to handle the first line
                continue
            accum += freq
            letters.append(letter)
            frequencies.append(freq)

        # normalize frequencies
        frequencies = [i/accum for i in frequencies]

    # you need to keep a list of letters, otherwise how do you
    # know to which letter does each frequency belong?
    return letters, frequencies
```

Comment: thank yo for this explanation, although I'm getting a  typeerror on the "accum += freq" line. 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str't, is there anything wrong with how I insert the data in the text file?

Comment: yup, my mistake. I corrected it by changing the `pass` inside the except to `continue` to discard the first line.

Comment: thank you, although it seems like I got another message on
letter, freq = line.split(';')

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). That's why I'm wondering if I've written the text file wrong.